# PostgreSQl pg_dump permission error?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Why a postgresql pg_dump not permitted with sudo which is producing permission denied error? Even root user is unable to pg_dump?

Comment: its sql permissions that you need to be looking at - what user is connected to the server at the time and what permissions does said user have against the db - If you are logged into the server using an admin account then make sure you have SA permissions at server level that will suffice

Comment: how do you who is superuser?

Comment: you need to read permissions and roles here's a useful link:   https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/role-attributes.html

Answer (score 2):

Use `pg_dump -U postgres [other options] databasename` to connect to the database as superuser while you perform the dump.

The database user is something different from the operating system user.

Comment: Hi , I am getting this error

pg_dump: reading extensions
pg_dump: identifying extension members
pg_dump: reading schemas
pg_dump: reading user-defined tables
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for relation provider_seq
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: LOCK TABLE londiste.provider_seq IN ACCESS SHARE MODE

while running  sudo pg_dump -U username_db -Z 9 -v b_db | aws s3 cp - s3://t_bucket.com/beta.dump.gz

What might i be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This will help your:

PGPASSWORD=[your password] pg_dump -U [your user name] [options] [dbname]

This way you will run pg_dump with previously exported password.